# How to make AWT draw on grid on a rectangle that is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I am a student in the process of making a Tic Tac Toe game, and currently have most of the UI and grid itself. I know AWT is out of data and Swing is much more informative and useful, but I am being taught and have the most resources on AWT. I currently have 5 classes:

GUI Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI{
    JFrame frame1;
    Board board1;
    Buttons buttons;
    MyMenu menu1;

    public GUI() {
        frame1 = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        board1 = new Board(3,3 ,200);
        buttons = new Buttons(this);
        menu1 = new MyMenu(this);
    }

    public void start () {
        frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        board1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame1.setMenuBar(menu1);
        frame1.add(board1);
        frame1.add(buttons);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.start();
    }
    
    public void setBackground (Color c) {
        board1.setBackground(c);
    }
    
    public void closeGame() {
        frame1.dispose();
    }
}
```

Board Class:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;

public class Board extends Canvas {
    Cell[][] array;
    int rows, cols;
    public Board(int rows, int cols, int size) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        array = new Cell[rows][cols];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            int y = r * size;
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                int x = c * size;
                array[r][c] = new Cell(x, y, size);
            }   
        }
        setSize(cols*size,rows*size);
    }
    
    public int getNumRows() {
        return rows;
    }
    
    public int getNumCols () {
        return cols;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for (Cell[] row : array) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                cell.paint(g);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        draw(g);
    }
}
```

Cell Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;

public class Cell
{
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int size;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    Cell[][] array = new Cell[rows][cols];
    public Cell(int x, int y, int size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void fillArray() {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            int y = r * size;
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                int x = c * size;
                array[r][c] = new Cell(x, y, size);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
    }
}
```

Button Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Buttons extends Panel implements ActionListener {
    Button test;
    Button giveIn;
    GUI gui;

    public Buttons(GUI gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
        giveIn = new Button("GIVE UP!");
        this.add(giveIn);
        giveIn.addActionListener(this);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()== giveIn) {
            gui.closeGame();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have another class, implementing a `Menu`, but didn't feel it was necessary to include. How hard would and how would I implement it so when I click a rectangle on my grid, something is painted onto that specific rectangle? I understand I would need a mouse listener, and some sort of if statement on my paint method, as well as some methods that return the cell or rectangle clicked. How is something like this implemented?

Comment: First, you want to make your data model correct.  A board has many cells;  therefore, the Board class should have an array of Cells (which it does).  A Cell instance represents just one cell;  it should not contain an array at all.

Comment: *"I also have another class, .. but didn't feel it was necessary to include."* Don't post the `Menu` class or 4 separate classes, but one [mre]. An MRE includes everything needed to run the code and see the problem, with nothing else besides that. *"I know AWT is out of data and Swing is much more informative and useful, but I am being taught and have the most resources on AWT."* Only the components should not be used, and questions using all Swing components will get better answers, as even most of us who *ever* used AWT components have mostly forgotten the details.